# Structure my database on Firebase with user data and product data

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am doing a project about Buying and Selling stuff, just like a marketplace. I using React and Firebase in my project.

The question is what is the best way to structure my Database:
Problem: 
My current Database is:

```
 Root ---

      ---Users //data about the user: id, username, avatar, customer rating...
      ---SellData //include data about the Seller ads: title, price, description, image,...
      ---BuyData  //include data about the Buyer ads: title, price, description, image,...
```

Then, in my homepage, I want to display a list item with each item have this information: userName, Avatar, customer rating, title, price. So it is a combine between Users and SellData.

Should I add more user data to my Root/SellData or Root/BuyData  because those filed just have product information, not the user information? But if I do it, my database will be very big when it scales. 
Is there any different solution for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NoSQL world, you should not be afraid to duplicate data and denormalize your data model. Here is a "famous" post about NoSQL data-modelling approaches: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Instead of designing your data-model from a pure database optimization perspective (normalization in the SQL world) you should, in the NoSQL world, think about it from a query perspective, trying to minimize the number of queries for a given screen/use case.

So it is totally valid to duplicate the `User` data in the `SellData` and `BuyData` records/nodes. This way, in one query you will get all the needed info for your homepage.

I don't know which database you are using, but to keep the different records in synch you can use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method for the Realtime database or a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) for Firestore.